# Python Regex: why doesn't python accept my pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I want to write Python regex that takes a string of pattern:

> "u'Johns's Place',"

and returns:

> Johns's Place

It should locate the character 'u', the apostrophe comes after it and then the apostrophe that comes before the comma and returns what there is between these two apostrophes.

Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
title = "u'Johns's Place',"
print re.sub(r"u'([^\"']*)',", r"\"\1\"", title)
```

however, I still got the entire string

> "u'Johns's Place',"

with no filtering.

Do you know how it can be resolved?

Comment: I'm suspicious about the `u` in your string. How are you getting this string?

Comment: actually this 'u' is supposed to mention 'unicode'

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why I'm suspicious about that. I think you should explain *how* you are getting that string, because this is smelling like an XY problem.

Comment: well, I read a json file and then I want to parse to.

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match, your character class matches `John`, then the `'` and then there is no comma.

Comment: What I am getting at, is that Python is setting that `u` to indicate it is a *unicode* string. There are idiomatic ways to handle this in Python. This is why I think you need to provide more information in what you are doing and how you are getting this *exactly*, in order to provide the right answer here instead of incorrectly parsing the string this way.

Comment: What idiomatic ways to handle it do you know?

Comment: You defined the class `[^\"']`, which means any character not `"` or `'`. Pretty sure there's a `'` in `John's`.

Comment: The application that is creating that JSON file in the first place is doing something wrong; maybe it is double-encoding somehow. You shouldn't be getting that `u` prefix in JSON output. Is that application under your control? If so can you post the code?

Comment: I've asked twice so far, maybe third time will be a charm.

Comment: @CrazySynthax It's fine that you go ahead and replace whatever characters you want. In the end it is your solution, but the fact that you are getting those unicode characters and in a weird way is an indication that the data is not being loaded properly, or possibly another issue. So, the *idomatic ways* there are to show how to solve this is dependent on what it is you are actually doing. Without the details, then there is no point to have the back and forth.

Answer (score 7):

Python doesn't accept your pattern because of the middle `'` in `"John's"`. It isn't followed by a comma, as described in your pattern. The matching cannot continue to look for a `',` because you only allow characters that aren't `"` or `'` with `[^\"']*`.

If you want to parse JSON with Python, use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) package, not regexen applied to escaped unicode strings.

Comment: OK. But there is a comma after Place'. So I expect python to ignore the comma in John's and catch the comma after "Place'"

Comment: @CrazySynthax: The matching cannot continue, you forbid it with `[^\"']*`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Python much but this regex should solve your problem

```
^u'(.*)',$
```

from the beginning match the u and single quote, capture anything after that until the single quote and comma at the end

```
print re.sub(r"^u'(.*)',$", r"\"\1\"", title)
```

remove ^ and $ if there's more to your string than the replaced (in other words, if there is any context)

Answer (score 0):

After making a bigger research I found this package https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It can make you read a JSON file without putting u'..' for every string.

```
import simplejson as json
import requests

response_json = requests.get(<url-address>)
current_json = json.loads(response_json.content)
```

current_json will not have the character 'u' at the beginnig of every string.

It answers my question partially because it returns keys and values that are delimited by a single quote mark(') and not by quotation marks(") as it's needed in JSON format.